# Setting html of a component in a panel sencha touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

i searched for my problem there is alot of questions and answers i found but none was useful to me
I have a xtype: 'component', in my panel i want to set dynamically htmlon panel show for it 
HERE is my component code

```
{
    xtype: 'component',
    itemId: 'dashboardwelcomenote',
    style: 'text-align: center'
},
```

here is my controller

```
var welcomename = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#dashboardwelcomenote')[0];
welcomename.setHtml('welcome');
```

i want it on panel show
any luck for me ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of itemId you can use reference as follow:

```
{
        xtype: 'component',
        reference: 'dashboardwelcomenote',
        style: 'text-align: center'
}
```

Now on panel show or we can say init function of controller i.e page load, you can write:

```
this.lookupReference('dashboardwelcomenote').setHtml('welcome');
```

Here, "this" is the controller itself.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning :)

Comment: didnt work??? that is not a solution for it. i am getting component by itemId but setting html fot it thats the problem for me   your code says that this is not a function

Comment: its working on my end.. can you please tell me what exactly is the error? if you are in a controller you can always have "this" as scope of it.

Comment: it says this.lookupReference is not a function

Comment: what is "this" inside your controller? is it the controller only? then it should definitely work, or else can you provide a fiddle or something to solve your issue?

Comment: i am really missing something but i dont know what its been two days i am suffering from this little problem ;)

Comment: come to chat please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139815/discussion-between-salman-hassan-okz-and-harshit-shah).

Comment: please come to chat.. i'm in

Answer (score 0):

Try update  here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tb7)..  [Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#method-update)

Comment: thanks for the answer please read my question again i have a component in panel and Update is not working

Comment: I updated my fiddle to have a component in panel and it works.  Maybe fork my fiddle and get a demo.

Comment: thanks for reply again but the thing is that i did try update its not working

Comment: you are right but i have an event on panel show event and i want it to set html dynamically on panel show  for that component